# Issues using VNC Viewer to connect to raspberry pi running AIY

Tags: pi-2, vnc, raspberry-pi-os

I've set up my raspberry 3 Model B to run on the 2021-04-02 version of the Google AIY SD card image as shown here: https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/releases

The problem I'm having is when I try to connect to my pi using VNC viewer from my laptop using the default raspberry pi username/password combo, it keeps telling me the username or password is incorrect when I know it isn't.

I've tried using VNC and the latest version of Raspbian on the pi and it connects with no issues, so I have to presume there's some issue with using VNC to connect to the pi when running the AIY image. I appreciate it hasn't been updated in a while so can see how that could be causing issues? Thanks.